# Fusing the $\mathrm{PGL}(2,11)$ conjugacy classes of $\mathrm{Aut}(M_{12})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

Is there an embedding of $\mathrm{Aut}(M_{12})$ into the automorphism group of some larger sporadic group that fuses its two conjugacy classes of $\mathrm{PGL}(2,11)$ subgroups?

Answer (score 1):

[Norton and Wilson - Maximal subgroups of the Harada–Norton group](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(86)90192-4) seems to imply that $\mathrm {HN} \rtimes C_2$ works, along with its overgroups $\mathbb{B}$ and $\mathbb{M}$.

Edit:… or not. This cannot be true, at least according to GAP, so I must’ve misunderstood the paper.